# Static pages in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I have a noobish question. Probably a silly one.
I have a static html page; that I want to deploy with my existing app on jboss. 
I put my static page xyz.html in my xyz-app.war folder in jboss.

I restarted the jboss and tried to hit
http://localhost:8080/xyz-app/xyz.html

it doesn't come up as the control goes to Ruby Routes controller. I am running Rails code (JRUBY) and Java both togather.

How can I bypass route lookup and show the page? It currently says no route found for xyz.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application's `web.xml` must have a `url-pattern` set up which catches the `xyz.html` request. You need to refine that `url-pattern`, making sure it only catches requests you want to go to jruby. Any request that comes in which isn't caught by a `url-pattern` will be served as a static file.

Comment: unfortunately it's a temp file that I just want for now and probably won't be part of my code base later. Is that the only way? Is there no temp workaround?

Comment: Not really, unless you can convince your ruby controller to pass the request through back to the container again.